# Sencha Ext.tip.Tooltip anchorSize not being set

Tags: extjs, tooltip

I am using Sencha's Ext.tip.Tooltip and I am trying to adjust the size of the the little triangle anchor attached the tooltip. Ext.tip.Tooltip has a config called anchorSize but it appears to change nothing.

Has anyone else experienced this? How did you get around it?

Comment: can u create a fiddle? https://fiddle.sencha.com

Comment: Extjs version ? If possible please give fiddle link.

Comment: I don't have time to create a fiddle right now sorry. At work.